# Help Finding Story Of Telepathic Kids

Tags: story-identification

I need help remembering a story/book that I read in elementary school, but I can't remember the name, characters, or a major part of the plot of the story. Here is what I can remember:

Yhere was a boy and girl. They were probably kids and the story started with them figuring out they could communicate with their minds. I believe they run away at some point, but I have no idea what part of the plot this was (it may have been to locate another person or "thing"). I do remember them at a "library" but don't remember why they went there.

I also believe the story ends with them at a carnival, but I'm having doubts that it was there. In the end they meet up with whatever this other person/thing was, and I remember the story saying the other person was in pajamas and possibly even the boy and girl were, but again my memory is sketchy.

Comment: Is this story set in the "normal" world? Apart from the library and the carnival, this sounds a bit like John Wyndham's The Crysalids.

Comment: From what I can remember, it was in the normal world. I looked at the plot for "The Crysalids" and that's not the story but I'm sure it's on the right track.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be [Into the Dream](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0141308141) by William Sleator? The grade level (3 and up) matches your description, as do the details I'm reading about it.

The two main characters are a boy and a girl who discover that they are sharing dreams. This leads them to discover their ability to telepathically communicate. Their dreams often involve a haunting ferris wheel (the carnival you mention), and they realize that they have to go rescue a boy (the someone you mention).

Comment: Wow... spot on! Thanks a lot. I thought I would never find what story that was! Thanks a bunch! Too bad its hard to find as an AudioBook.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU for posting the answer to this. I've been looking for the name of this book for an hour or more.

Comment: @Azi You're welcome :) And thanks for commenting - I didn't even know this question was migrated here!