# Id kids scifi book series

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, soft-sci-fi

As child (around 1985, 10yo) I read a series of scifi books for children - in german.  I am unable to recall their name so I wonder if you can help id them.

It is about a group of kids.  They were recruited by the professor(?) to do missions on other planets.  They are accompanied by a telepathic dog that acts as translator.  The dog is actually an alien from a planet of telepathic dogs (maybe wolves).

The world is not particularly advanced and is unaware of the professor and his assistants.  The parents and families of the kids don't play a role.  But I think there were siblings in the group (brother and small sister if I recall correctly).

The professor works in hiding with his assistants.  I don't recall any assistant ever being important.  The professor has a fleet of spaceships that are described similar to star wars star destroyers - huge triangular ships, but described clean.  Around earth they cloak - usually inside clouds. The children never meet anybody onboard the ships, they are completely run by computers.

I recall particular story points:

- One time the children were told to go to "finis terra" for pickup. (the westernmost point of europe, located in spain).  They were then going up in a transparent "lift" to a ship, hidden inside a cloud with invisible walls.
- The children were having fun ordering all their favourite sweets from the food processor on a ship.
- The planet of telepathic dogs was enslaved - or at least the race of dogs was enslaved.  The telepathic dog with the kids was kind of a refugee.  In one early book the children play a role in freeing the telepathic dogs.  Their dog brings this up several times reminding the children to search for peaceful solutions.

Story points I am not certain are:

- There is an evil organisation hunting the professor.
- After missions they meet the professor and assistants for a celebration
- I don't think there are robots or AI around.  All the ships and other machines were "programmed".

Comment: Probably not the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/175125/33591, but may be worth linking anyway.

Comment: Interesting similar enough to ring a bell.  I wonder if it could be a later book in the same series.  The ones I recall focus more on fancy foreign planets and more childish themes but maybe the author wanted to target older readers over the course of the series.